# Combing selectors that are saved as vars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's possible to combine the first 2 lines to something like line 3 where the 2 selectors are separated by `,`

```
$('#divid input[name=some]').val('');
$('#divid input[name=thing]').val('');

$('#divid input[name=some], #divid input[name=thing]').val('');
```

But if I have them saved as objects `obj1` and `obj2`, how do I select them together the same way?

```
var obj1 = $('#divid input[name=some]');
var obj2 = $('#divid input[name=thing]');
```

I tried all this but they didn't work. Can it be done?

```
obj1,obj2.val('');
(obj1,obj2).val('');
$(obj1,obj2).val('');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
var obj1 = $('#divid input[name=some]');
var obj2 = $('#divid input[name=thing]');
obj1.add(obj2).val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)**